# Can I make a docker container respect the local mkcert CA?

Tags: linux, docker, certificate

I'm using `mkcert` to create a local CA so that Google Chrome accepts my local development certificates.

Now I have faced a new problem. I have a testing docker container that comes up, and it shares the local network, so all of the local DNS entries would work inside the container too.

However, the locale development certificate is invalid inside the test container.

For example when I try to use headless browser to run UI tests, or when I want to get the lighthouse score through CLI, it breaks because the local certificate is not valid for headless browser inside the container.

What can I do to make my local CA valid for my local containers too?

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this but you would need to the the root CA that mkcert creates and add it to the root certificates of the container.

You can use `mkcert -CAROOT` to get the path to the root certificate files. Afterwards you add them to your containers somehow, that depends on the containers that you use.

Comment: This works for me. Tested on mkcert --version v1.4.4